# Permanent residency in Germany with an expired passport

Tags: germany, resident-permit, blue-card

In 2020 I will get my PR in Germany, however in 2021 my passport will expire in May and I will have to wait till September to reach 30 years old and be able to apply at my embassy for a new passport (from the age of 29 till 30, males are not able to renew their passports unless they give a final exemption from the military service).

Are these 4 months going to be a problem? I am not willing to travel in this period anyway, but can I expect any trouble with the Auslanderbehörde because of my expired passport in that period?

Comment: I am egyptian and i will have similar situation like yours next year! I was wondering how you are/did manage this problem. I wont be able to renew my passport for a year and i am looking for an alternative so i can keep my job here. It would be great to hear from you! Thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* and *Niederlassungserlaubnis* are documents of their own. It doesn't matter if you got the plastic card or passport sticker either. They are still valid even if the passport expires.

Comment: This seems a sensible answer (although an official source would help), but isn't the foreigner supposed to maintain a valid passport?  Does an *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* or a *Niederlassungserlaubnis* count as a *Passersatz?*

Comment: You need a valid passport. But failure to have one does not result in deportation. Theoretically you could be fined and have your residency permit revoked, but there are very common cases in which someone could not refresh their passports – e.g. dissidents – and equal treatment of all cases is the norm.

Comment: So, Is it better to inform the Auslanderbehörde or just glide over these few months and go there once I get a new passport?

Comment: A lawyer put it this: You better inform the German officials about the situation in advance so they don't take any action on this. They also tell you what to do. https://www.frag-einen-anwalt.de/Pass-abgelaufen-was-ist-mit-der-Niederlassungserlaubnis--f261034.html

Comment: Okay, then at that point I will inform the Auslanderbehörde and also I will seek an official paper from my Embassy explaining that I have to wait for some months to be able to apply for a new Passport.